# navigate from one page to another

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am new with android this is my 1st demo app. I am trying to navigate from one page to another. But i am not able to navigate to another page i have a button in may main xml file and on licking it is moving to an another xml nextpage. I have 2 java class : 1st MianAcitvity, nextpagejava. 2 xml : activity_main, nextpage

My code : manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androiddemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="nextpagejava" ></activity>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.androiddemo;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.drm.DrmStore.Action;
 import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
 import android.widget.Button;

     public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bnt);
           bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              / / TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
         }); 
         }

          @Override
          public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
          return true;
         }

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.bnt:
                 Intent in = new Intent(this, nextpagejava.class);
                 startActivity(in);
             break;


          }
          }
          }
```

acitivity_main.xml

```
       <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

         <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/clicktxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"        
        />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/bnt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me"
        />
```

can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

**First One** - In android manifest file write activity name with package name like below.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.androiddemo.nextpagejava" ></activity>
```

**Second One** - In MainActivity.java file use below code and remove .

```
 bt.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**Remove this**

```
 bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              / / TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
         });
```

Comment: It is not compulsory to write Activity Name along with package name.It wont cause any problem

Comment: @AndroidCrazy If he don't want to write package name then he must user .(dot)ActivityName if the activity is in the same pacakge.

Comment: ya that's true,he need to put .(dot)

Comment: hi i did it and found it working. But i have back button on next page but i am not able to view anything the page is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this..

```
 Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code remove following code

```
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  / / TODO Auto-generated method stub

               }
             }); `


and put  bt.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: hi i did it and found it working. But i have back button on next page but i am not able to view anything the page is blank.

Answer (score 0):

check this code which is edited from your java class.

```
package com.example.androiddemo;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.drm.DrmStore.Action;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bnt);
       bt.setOnClickListener(this); 
     }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
      return true;
     }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      switch(v.getId()){
      case R.id.bnt:
             Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, nextpagejava.class);
             startActivity(in);
         break;


      }
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. the `nextpagejava` activity must be declared in the manifest with the full class name (including package)
2. You have attached an empty `OnClickListener` to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement  onClickListener when you have given

```
 bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              / / TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
         });
```

and remove one of the onClick() method.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do for moving from one activity to another ,is the following

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainAcitvity.this, NextPage.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Main Activity file use Below code :

bt.setOnClickListener(this);